# Finding and replacing element in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am new to the python programming and wanted to know how can I iterate over elements below then replace strings and make my data list look like below. Thank you in advance.

```
[{u 'name': u 'xxx',
u 'data': [
    [u 'last_00_10', x],
    [u 'last_11_20', x],
    [u 'last_21_30', x],
],
u 'id': x }]
```

After replacing string, I want it to look like below

```
[{u 'name': u 'xxx',
u 'data': [
    [u '0-10 Days', x],
    [u '11-20 Days', x],
    [u '21-30 Days', x],
],
u 'id': x }]
```

Comment: The space after each `u` will give a syntax error, and you don't need it anyway if you are using Python 3.  Please show what you have tried so far and any specific issues you have.

Comment: [For each](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) element in the value for the ```data``` item, [split the first item on ```_```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), then take the last two items from the split - turn them into integers and use them as [arguments to a format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) then reconstruct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list which contains a dictionary.  The 'data' key in the dictionary contains a list.  You want to iterate over that list and replace the first item in the list with different text.

```
x = 1
your_data = [{u'name': u'xxx',
u'data': [
    [u'last_00_10', x],
    [u'last_11_20', x],
    [u'last_21_30', x],
],
u'id': x }]

for item in your_data[0]['data']:
    item_split = item[0].split('_')
    item[0] = str(int(item_split[1])) + '-' + str(int(item_split[2])) + ' Days'

print(your_data)
```

This gives:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'xxx', 'data': [['00-10 Days', 1], ['11-20 Days', 1], ['21-30 Days', 1]]}]
```

Comment: Ahh! I almost had it right. Thank you. This works as expected!

Comment: This does not give a single digit for values < 10.

Answer (score 0):

first, why you put 1 dict on a list? you'll put other dicts inside?, but I'll use your structure..
you can do something like this(I named your list L): and x = "" to work..(it's a non defined yet variable..

```
x = ""


L = [
        {
            u'name': u'xxx',
            u'data': [
                        [u'last_00_10', x],
                        [u'last_11_20', x],
                        [u'last_21_30', x],
                    ],
            u'id': x 
        }
]

newData = [u"0-10 Days", u'11-20 Days', u'21-30 Days']
for i in range(len( L[0][u'data'] )):
    L[0][u'data'][i][0] = newData[i]
```

it'll work as you want..

I corrected the spaces between u'string' on the code

Answer (score 0):

This almost give what you want:

```
import re

x = 42
stuff = [{u'name': u'xxx',
          u'data': [
         [u'last_00_10', x],
         [u'last_11_20', x],
         [u'last_21_30', x],
                   ],
          u'id': x }]

for row in stuff[0]['data']:
    row[0] = re.sub(r'last_(\d+)_(\d+)',
                    r'\1-\2 Days', row[0])
    print(row)
```

Gives:

```
['00-10 Days', 42]
['11-20 Days', 42]
['21-30 Days', 42]
```

If you want single digit numbers ("00" to "0") there is a bit more work.

```
def subit(m):
    f1, f2 = m.groups()[:2]
    return "%d-%d Days" % (int(f1), int(f2))

for row in stuff[0]['data']:
    row[0] = re.sub(r'last_(\d+)_(\d+)', subit, row[0])
    print(row)
```

Gives:

```
['0-10 Days', 42]
['11-20 Days', 42]
['21-30 Days', 42]
```